AWS EMR : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delta.tables'; 'delta' is not a package
I am creating EMR-7.0.0 and in configurations passing [{"Classification":"delta-defaults",  "Properties":{"delta.enabled":"true"} }] with applications Hadoop 3.3.6,Hive 3.13 and Spark 3.5.0
My code is like :
`import logging
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkConf
from delta.tables import *`

`class DeltaTest:
    def __init__(self):
        logging.info("DeltaTest Started")

    def createSparkSession(self):
        try:
            conf = (SparkConf()
                    .setAppName("DeltaTest")
                    .set("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
                    .set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
                    .set("spark.jars","/usr/share/aws/delta/lib/delta-core.jar, /usr/share/aws/delta/lib/delta-storage.jar, /usr/share/aws/delta/lib/delta-storage-s3-dynamodb.jar")
                    )

            spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
            logging.info("Spark session created successfully.")
            return spark
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("Error creating Spark session: %s", str(e))
            raise
`

The reads and writes are working fine but when i am trying to perfrom Merge I am getting an error,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delta.tables'; 'delta' is not a package
How to solve this ? I am referencing AWS article https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/Deltaintro.html
